# .Net Compact Framework: Alternative to SynchronizationContext

Tags: .net, compact-framework, synchronizationcontext

I'm working on a Program for Windows CE 6, which consists of two projects within an Visual Studio 2008 solution, written in VB.Net. Before, I wrote a similar program for the Windows desktop, so I want to try to reuse as much code as possible.

The generic structure is: The first project contains the frontend gui, the second one is library for serial communication. This library should be reusable for other GUI's and must not depend on graphical stuff, for example `Control`  .

In that second library-project I'm using a `SerialPort`-instance, the receivement of data is handled via the `SerialPort.DataReceived` event. As `DataReceived` occurs in an second thread, I'm using `SynchronizationContext` in the *desktop variant*, `Invoke` is not avaiable to not depend on graphical stuff. The following is an simple example:

```
Public Class Comm
    Private dllContext As SynchronizationContext
    Private port as SerialPort

    Public Sub New()
        dllContext = SynchronizationContext.Current
        port = new SerialPort("COM1")
    End Sub

    Public Sub port_DataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles port.DataReceived
        Dim data(-1) as Byte

        '         
        ' Read Received Data into the data-Variable, yet.
        ' 

        If (dllContext IsNot Nothing) then
            dllContext.Send(Sub() RaiseEvent DataReceived(Me, data), Nothing)
        Else
            RaiseEvent DataReceived(Me, data)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

When Porting this code to .Net CF, there is no `SynchronizationContext` available. I searched on the net, found these: 
http://www.planetgeek.ch/2009/02/03/part-i-mimic-synchronizationcontext-behaviour-on-net-cf/
http://www.planetgeek.ch/2009/02/15/part-ii-mimic-synchronizationcontext-behaviour-on-net-cf/
But the author is using Control.Invoke, which I don't want to use (it's in System.Windows.Forms)

As I found no other approaches over days, my question is: how can this be solved?

Thanks,

Christoph